# Why InnerHTML stopped working after updating the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, innerhtml

After updating my code, `innerHTML` stopped working all of sudden. It works in the console, but it does not show itself on the website. It happened between updating my CSS file, but I don't think that's the problem, because when using the old CSS file, it still does not work. I have the parameter `defer` in the script so it should work. What could be the problem?

```js
const cards = `
      <div class="board" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(${dimension_width}, auto)">
          ${items.map(item => `
              <div class="card" value="${findIn2dArray(addictions, item)}">
                  <div class="card-front"></div>
                  <div class="card-back"><img src="${imgs[item]}"></div>
              </div>
          `).join('')}
     </div>
  `
document.querySelector('.board-container').innerHTML = cards;
```

```css
.board,
.win {
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgb(33 33 33 / 25%);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #6A4694 0%, #71B6DA 50%, #6BFDE2 100%);
  transition: transform .6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.board {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.board-container.flipped .board {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(50deg);
}

.board-container.flipped .win {
  transform: rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="music-buttons">
  <button class="play-music"><i class="fa-solid fa-volume-high"></i></button>
  <button class="mute-music"><i class="fa-solid fa-volume-xmark"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="game">
  <div class="controls">
    <button class="start">Start</button>
    <button class="stop">Restart</button>
    <div class="stats">
      <div class="moves">0 moves</div>
      <div class="timer">time: 0 sec</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="board-container">
    <div class="board" data-dimension-width="2" data-dimension-height="2"></div>
    <div class="begin"></div>
    <div class="win">You won!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check for js errors in console?

Comment: Yep, there are none, besides some music errors, but they haven't interrupt innerHTML from working up to this point :)

Comment: check with semicolon after ending the cards template

Comment: Then your next stop is to put a breakpoint in the code and see what happens when you get to the innerHTML. The code you have currently does not run, if you replaced the content of cards with "test", it runs fine

Comment: Debugging steps: confirm that the page still has `.board-container` before your code runs; add a console.log statement after the innerHTML change announcing that the code has finished; once you see that, use browser DevTools to verify whether the HTML has actually been changed.

Comment: Thank you for all ideas I will try them and notify you asap :D